# Optional messages moderation in Firebase Realtime DB chat?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing a chat using [Firebase Realtime DB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). There's a requirement, that some chatrooms can show new messages by default, but messages in different chatrooms have to be approved first before displaying them.

The DB structure in Firebase is nested like this:

```
/chat/$roomID/$messageID/
```

and each message object is structured as follows:

```
{
    user: string
    content: string
    isApproved: boolean
    clientStamp: number // client-side unix timestamp
    serverStamp: number // server-side unix timestamp, via `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`
}
```

Having only the display-by-default chatrooms would be easy - I'd order the data by `serverStamp`:

```
let query = DBConn.ref('chat/' + roomID).orderByChild('serverStamp').limitToLast(50);
query.on("value", snapshot => {
     // set the list of messages to display
     this.appendSnapshot(snapshot);
});
```

The approve-first rule makes this approach difficult however. The obvious solution would be to show only messages with attribute `isApproved` set to `true`. But if I'd query for the last N messages ordered by timestamp, and someone would post N unapproved messages, then that would oust any of the approved messages from the query result and the chat would be empty. Realtime DB has the following limitation, which makes it impossible to query by both timestamp + `isApproved`:

> You can only use one order-by method at a time

So right now I'm workarounding it the following way:

- messages are ordered by `clientStamp` (clientside unix timestamp) instead of `serverStamp`
- when sending a new message to server, I divide the value of `clientStamp` by two, which mean these new messages will never oust the already approved older messages from the query result (since their timestamp has higher value)
- when a message gets approved, the value of `clientStamp` is set to a value of `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` (serverside time), which pushes it to the top of the chat query (`orderByChild('serverStamp')`)

... but this is rather a quick workaround. Is there any way how to make this work nicely for both display-by-default and approve-first chatrooms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your approach with setting the timestamp as part of an approval flow.

The more common solution is the one I documented in [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Here that'd mean you have a property `isApproved_serverStamp` where you store the combined values of the `isApproved` and `serverStamp` properties, so like `true_1632065222747`. You can then query for the most recent approved messages with:

```
DBConn.ref('chat/' + roomID).orderByChild('isApproved_serverStamp').startAt("true_").limitToLast(50)
```

Comment: hm... using `.startAt('true_')` sure makes it better, plus that column can be guarded via Rules, unlike `clientStamp`. I guess I'll take it, thanks. Do you think the index on given column is less efficient since all the values now basically start with `true_`?

Comment: Index efficiency is outside of your control, but the database server typically handles such indexed quite well for hundreds of thousands of nodes. You'll inedeed need to implement [query based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query) to ensure users can't request unapproved messages

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the thoroughness of the comment. I sure take the Security Rules into account (that's what I was referring to by `Rules` in my previous comment).